# How are funds returned in the Solidity docs Simple Open Auction example?

Tags: solidity, contract-development

I was looking at the [simple open auction example](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.3/solidity-by-example.html#simple-open-auction) from the solidity docs. I don't understand the withdrawal part where a previous bidder wishes to withdraw his funds after he has been over bid.

This is an excerpt from the code.

```js
/// Withdraw a bid that was overbid.
function withdraw() public returns (bool) {
    uint amount = pendingReturns[msg.sender];
    if (amount > 0) {
        // It is important to set this to zero because the recipient
        // can call this function again as part of the receiving call
        // before `send` returns.
        pendingReturns[msg.sender] = 0;

        if (!payable(msg.sender).send(amount)) {
            // No need to call throw here, just reset the amount owing
            pendingReturns[msg.sender] = amount;
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

How are the funds returned? Or is the process facilitated by some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The funds are returned by this line

```
payable(msg.sender).send(amount)
```

where `msg.sender` will receive `amount`.

Comment: I think I understand, the if the condition will execute, if it fails the pendingReturns amount will return to the additional deposit. This syntax is new to me!

Comment: @ArjunBhobe That's correct. The function `send()` returns false when the transfer has failed.